# Getting Internal Server Error while accessing the libindicate documentation!

Tags: indicator

I'm building an indicator app and I'm trying to connect to
http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/c/indicate/ for getting reference documentation. However it gives me the Internal Server Error, so I'm currently blocked by that. Would you tell me if the documentation is available elsewhere and if there's any plan to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most links for indicator API/documentation are dead, but I have managed to find a few [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/491886/67335).